# python error "quote_from_bytes() expected bytes"

Tags: python

So I have this code snippet that returns an error whenever I try to execute it.

Below is the code, it's supposed to make a google image search based on flexible amount of string arguments.

```
@bot.command()
async def randomimage(*args):
    """Displays a random image of said thing"""
    q = ''

    for arg in enumerate(args):
      q += urllib.parse.quote(arg) + '+'

    f = urllib2.urlopen('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?q=' + q + '&v=1.0&rsz=large&start=1')
    data = json.load(f)
    f.close()
```

I get this error when I try to execute it however:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)

File "bot.py", line 39, in randomimage
    q += urllib.parse.quote(arg) + '+'
  File "parse.py", line 775, in quote
    return quote_from_bytes(string, safe)
  File "parse.py", line 800, in quote_from_bytes
    raise TypeError("quote_from_bytes() expected bytes")
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Is `args` a list of strings? If so, you should convert them to bytes for urllib.parse.quote to work properly.

Change `q += urllib.parse.quote(arg) + '+'` to `q += urllib.parse.quote(arg.encode('utf-8')) + '+'` or `q += urllib.parse.quote(bytes(arg)) + '+'`

Comment: After doing so, I get a new error, AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Just noticed the other problem here. `for arg in enumerate(args):` should be `for arg in args`. Or if you need to use enumerate (for debugging or other reasons), it should be `for _, arg in enumerate(args)`